# How to reduce if else statements in this code?

Tags: java, oop

The code here is basically used to decide the string based on the roll of the die. There are alot of statements in this, i really could use some help in reducing this. 
I have looked at some methods on the internet, but they are not fitting in.

```
public String generatePassageSection(){
        int roll = roll();
        if(roll<=2 && roll>=1) 
        {
            return "passage goes straight for 10 feet.";
        }

        else if(roll<=5 && roll>=3) 
        {
            return "passage ends in door to a chamber.";
        }

        else if(roll<=7 && roll>=6) 
        {
            return "door to right (main passage continues straight for 10 ft)";
        }

        else if(roll<=9 && roll>=8) 
        {
            return "door to left (main passage continues straight for 10 ft)";
        }

        else if(roll<=11 && roll>=10) 
        {
            return "passage turns to left and continues for 10 ft";
        }

        else if(roll<=13 && roll>=12) 
        {
            return "passage turns to right and continues for 10 ft";
        }

        else if(roll<=16 && roll>=14) 
        {
            return "passage ends in door to chamber";
        }

        else if(roll==17) 
        {
            return "Stairs, (passage continues straight for 10 ft)";
        }

        else if (roll<=19 && roll>=18) 
        {
            return "Dead end";
        }

        else if(roll==20)
        {
            return "Wandering Monster (passage continues straight for 10 ft)";
        }

        else 
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You could use a `switch`

Comment: You could put the strings into a map, but I don't think reducing the if statements here is necessary. Your code looks fine as it is.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really great question. Since every if-else is the same; You check if some roll is within some bounds and then return a string, you can just use an enumeration. The enum name can be improved, as well as the element names, relative to what you're working on and representing with this data.

```java
    public String generatePassageSection() {
        int roll = roll();

        Message message = Stream.of(Message.values()).filter(m -> m.inBounds(roll)).findAny().orElse(null);

        return message == null ? null : message.message;
    }

    enum Message {
        FIRST(1, 2, "passage goes straight for 10 feed."),
        SECOND(3, 5, "passage ends in the door to a chamber."),
        THIRD(6, 7, "door to right (main passage continues straight for 10 ft)"),
        FOURTH(9, 10, "door to left (main passage continues straight for 10 ft)"),
        FIFTH(10, 11, "passage turns to left and continues for 10 ft"),
        SIXTH(12, 13, "passage turns to right and continues for 10 ft"),
        SEVENTH(14, 16, "passage ends in door to chamber"),
        EIGHTH(17, 17, "Stairs, (passage continues straight for 10 ft)"),
        NINTH(18, 19, "Dead end"),
        TENTH(20, 20, "Wandering Monster (passage continues straight for 10 ft)");

        ;
        private final int minimumRollInclusive;

        private final int maximumRollInclusive;

        private final String message;

        Message(int minimumRollInclusive, int maximumRollInclusive, String message) {
            this.minimumRollInclusive = minimumRollInclusive;
            this.maximumRollInclusive = maximumRollInclusive;
            this.message = message;
        }

        boolean inBounds(int roll) {
            return roll >= minimumRollInclusive && roll <= maximumRollInclusive;
        }

    }

    int roll() {
        return 0; // use ur code
    }
```

Also, it should be noted that Enum#values creates a new array object every time its called so it would be worth caching that.

Comment: This is a clever solution, and I upvoted it for that reason.  However, I prefer my (updated) answer because to my eyes it has less "mechanism", i.e., I find a straightforward lookup to be simpler.  But this is a matter of style and thus is just one man's opinion.

Comment: Thanks Dave, yeah it definitely comes down to preference. One thing I would like to mention about your solution is that the underlying array can be modified during runtime which is a bit unsafe, even though you declared it final. Just a heads up man!

Comment: Modifiable - true, but ```private``` helps contain the risk, especially if all that stuff is embedded in small class of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer data structures over code.

```
final private static String text[] = {
    "passage goes straight for 10 feet.", // 1, 2
    "passage ends in door to a chamber.", // 3, 4, 5
    "door to right (main passage continues straight for 10 ft)", // 6, 7
    "door to left (main passage continues straight for 10 ft)", // 8, 9
    "passage turns to left and continues for 10 ft", // 10, 11
    "passage turns to right and continues for 10 ft", // 12, 13
    "passage ends in door to chamber", // 14, 15, 16
    "Stairs, (passage continues straight for 10 ft)", // 17
    "Dead end", // 18, 19
    "Wandering Monster (passage continues straight for 10 ft)" // 20
}

final private static int index[] = {
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9
}

public String generatePassageSection() {
    return text[index[roll()-1]];
}
```

The manually-constructed index array has implicit assumptions about the order and content of the text array. I judge this to be reasonable under the circumstances and scale of this routine; I don't recommend it as general practice.

This implicitly assumes roll() is known to reliably return a result in the range 1 to 20 inclusive; if you can't trust it, error checking should be added.

Comment: There was briefly an answer here I thought better than mine; it used double indexing to handle duplicates. But it got deleted for some reason. I'd incorporate that idea, but I don't want to steal in case the answer is coming back.

Comment: Since that answer did not come back, I incorporated (*aka* stole) the idea.

Comment: My change is, of course, consistent with [the fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to reduce the number of if statements, you could add an array of possible outcomes, index each outcome at their appropriate dice roll, then return the value at that index. I am not gonna write it all out for you, but it would look something a bit like this:

```
public String generatePassageSection(String[] diceRolls){
   return diceRolls[roll()];
}
```